# very simple column addition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm under the impression that SQL Server will allow me to perform addition such as

```
SELECT     val01, val02, val03 = (val01 + val02)
FROM       Table_1
```

so that val03 is the addition of the two previous columns. However, in this instance I am literally seeing value 1 next to value 2. Can you show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: WWhat are val01's and val02's datatypes? I guess char or similar?

Comment: What datatypes are val01 and val02?

Comment: brilliant!, wrong data type. THANK YOU

Comment: By the way, in case you are still under the impression of being allowed to do things like `val03 = (val01 + val02)`, I'm not sure what exactly has impressed you there, but if it's the `val03 = …` bit, then be aware that it's merely an alternative way of aliasing in SQL Server. It is precisely the same as `(val01 + val02) AS val03`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator has two uses in SQL Server:

- For **numbers** (`int`, `bigint`, `decimal`, etc) it is an **ADDITION** operator.
- For **strings** (`varchar`, `nvarchar`, `char`, etc) it is a **CONCATENATION** operator.

If you have numerical data in a string datatype field, you will see the second value appended to the first.

The solution is to either:

- **Use correct datatypes**.  If it's a number, the datatype should be numerical.
- **CAST to the correct datatype** - i.e.  `val03 = (CAST(val01 as int) + CAST(val02 as INT))`

Answer (score 1):

So val03 is a concatenation of val01 and val02 in your result list?  Like:

```
VAL01  VAL02  VAL03
    1      2   1  2
    4      5   4  5
```

In this case, either Val01 or Val02 are non-numerical columns, or maybe both.  Cast them:

```
SELECT val01, val02, val03 = (cast(val01 as float) + cast(val02 as float)) FROM Table_1
```

Or, alternatively, fix the column types.

Answer (score 0):

If your val01 and val02 columns are character or varchar, but contain numbers, the numbers are going to be concatenated in the syntax above.

If you want them to appear as numbers, you will need to use CAST or CONVERT on the val01 or val02 fields to get them to be added as numeric values.

Example:

SELECT val01, val02, val03 FROM Table_1
WHERE CAST(val03 as INT) = ((CAST val01 as INT) + (CAST val02 as INT))